In a table of updates, how would I get the latest update of one property for each record in one column?
Lets say a I have a table that tracks all updates to the services all customers have purchased. It records the customer, the service that is updated, how the service was updated (added or removed) and when the update happened.



id
Customer
Service
Removed/added
update_date




1
John Smith
Lawn Mowing
Removed
3-1-23


2
John Smith
Lawn Mowing
Added
6-1-22


3
John Smith
Fertilizing
Added
6-1-22


4
Jane Doe
Lawn Mowing
Added
7-15-23


5
Alex Reynolds
Lawn Watering
Added
6-18-23


6
Alex Reynolds
Lawn Mowing
Added
6-18-23



Lets say, I want to get the current state of Lawn mowing for each customer, I want to have each customer, and whether their last  Lawn Mowing update was added or removed, how would I write a query to get that result?

Could you please add your current attempt and explain what doesn't work as expected?

This is a made up scenario because I'm working with business data. I've been struggling to even figure out how to start to write the query to get what I need.

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. It would help if you show both sample input data and also the expected result in your question. But maybe this helps?: https://dbfiddle.uk/QRsqZv0K

Hint: filter your query by the service you are interested in and where the update date equals the max update date for that customer and service

I would solve this using a Common Table Expression and a rowNumber that's generated by ordering each update_date (desc) for each customer. Row 1 will then be the most recent date.
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        [Customer],
        [Service],
        [Removed/added],
        [update_date],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Customer] ORDER BY [update_date] DESC) AS [RowNum]
    FROM [fooTable]
    WHERE [Service] = 'Lawn Mowing'
)
SELECT
    [Customer],
    [Service],
    [Removed/added],
    [update_date]
FROM cte
    WHERE [RowNum] = 1

Note: [fooTable] should be replaced with whatever the actual table is.
